# Spotfire limit data by text

Tags: spotfire

I have a string column `[VEHICLE]` that contains row variations of `"car", "CAR", "car" and "car1"`. I'm trying to use a limit data by expression to exclude all of those variations. I've tried `Lower([VEHICLE]) ~= "*car*"` but it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: The post removed the wildcard asterisk before and after "car" in my expression.

Comment: No worries Chris. I think Niko and I should have set you up below. Let me know is that works out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. In Limit Data Using Expression use this instead.

```
IF(Lower([Vehicle]) ~= "car*",true,false)
```

or even better... in case you have car$ or something that isn't a-z

```
IF(Lower([Vehicle]) ~= "car.*",true,false)
```

or if you expect something to become before car... like thisCar1 use this:

```
IF(Lower([Vehicle]) ~= ".*car.*",true,false)
```

In the second example, `.` is any character and `*` is stating match 0 or more of this instance. Without the `*`, which is what you had, it's stating match 0 or more of instances of... nothing. You just have to give it something to reference.

Remeber `~=` uses Regular Expressions

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't need to surround this in an if statement since Lower([Vehicle]) ~= "car" and its variants resolve to a boolean true/false

Comment: @niko makes a great point and is absolutely right. This is just a coding habit of mine

Comment: Excellent, this works. Taken one step further, how can I make this "not like" "car" (e.g. <> ~= "car"). I know that doesn't work but and neither does "not ~= "car"" and neither does "not like "car"".

Comment: @Chris You can just swap the true and false. `IF(Lower([Vehicle]) ~= ".*car.*",false,true)`. This will give you everything that DOES NOT have car in it. Please accept and upvote correct answers. Cheers.